# HTTP URL splitting fails

Tags: c#

I have a server which returns images to a client. Whenever an image is returned, the client requests the next image (with a different url of course). This means that I have to grab the url request and somehow split it up and parse it on, so that my server knows which image is being requested.

I currently have the current setup:

This is where the request is being handled and as you can see, what I'm currently doing is asking specifically about the url where the image is. If the incoming request url is the same, then the image gets sent back. I need some kind of mechanism that will ask for the url of the image, depending on the url of the incoming request. So after returning image 0,0,0.png, the client will ask for 0,0,1.png and so on.

Any hint to how I can do this?

```
 if (p.http_url.Equals("/MapServer/tile/0/0/0"))
        {
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap("../MapServer/tile/0,0,0.png");
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            bmap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] buffer = memStream.ToArray();

            p.outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

I imagine it should be done with something similar to this but I've got a little stuck.

```
 public void urlSplitter()
    {
        string http_url_split = http_url;
        string[] splitString = http_url_split.Split('/');
        int index = splitString.Length - 1;
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. What part specifically are you having trouble with? What does this code do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: When the client sends a HTTP request to the server it currently looks like this: "GET /MapServer/tile/0/0/0 HTTP/1.1". 

This then gets split up and the "/MapServer/tile/0/0/0" part is sent to the GET request handler which is the first piece of code above as "http_url".

If that equals "/MapServer/tile/0/0/0" then the image at that location gets sent back. Now the client will ask for "/MapServer/tile/1/0/0", but I never enter the if-loop because now "http_url" is "/MapServer/tile/1/0/0".

What I'm asking about is a hint to how I can keep loading images when the http_url changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) to match the URL and fill in the matches in the file path:

```
Regex tileRegex = new Regex(@"/MapServer/tile/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)");

var matches = tileRegex.Match(p.http_url);

if (matches.Success)
{
    string path = "../MapServer/tile/{0},{1},{2}.png";

    path = string.Format(path, matches.Groups[1].Captures[0], 
                               matches.Groups[2].Captures[0],
                               matches.Groups[3].Captures[0]);

    Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(path);

    ...
}
```

Comment: When trying to do this I catch this exception: {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: i"}

Which as far as I can understand is when I'm using "i" as a parameter, it gets invalid somewhere. But so far I haven't been able to debug to what, how and why this is happening.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @Khaine775 Yeah, change the Regex to `/MapServer/tile/([0-9])/([0-9])/([0-9])` and start with group index `1` rather than `0`. Otherwise the only capture is the whole URL, which isn't all that useful (basically, it only validates the URL). Also, note that it will only work for single-digit numbers - if you need to support more digits as well, use `([0-9]+)` instead of `([0-9])`.

Comment: @Luaan Alright thank you. It's working now, even though I'm not returning the correct headers but that's a whole other case!

Answer (score 1):

You can also match the URL partially:

```
if (p.http_url.StartsWith("/MapServer/tile/"))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: But then he'll still needs code to map `/MapServer/tile/0/0/0` to `../MapServer/tile/0,0,0.png` (which could also be done with a simple string replace.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, in practice, your solution would often be better. A simple string replace might be a little too unbounded. I'd probably just `Split` the string by `/`. Or use ASP.NET MVC :D

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why OP insists on creating his own HTTP server.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm just trying to play around with the mechanics and learn something new on the way. It's not like it's going to be used for anything meaningful anyway.